# Bootstrap Grid, unable to separate them into desired columns space

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid, rows

I am new to programming and having difficulty in adjusting the bootstrap grids to fit my framework; I am trying to do a 3 columns side bar on the left, and followed by a 9 column main side bar on the right - but they appeared as 12 columns each after I input my code.

```
      <div class="content row">
      <?php include "_/components/php/snippet-carousel.php"; ?>

      <section class="col-md-3  col-md-pull-9  sidebar">
     <?php include "_/components/php/aside-social.php"; ?> 
           </section><!-- sidebar -->


            <section class="col-md-9  col-md-push-3  cont-grid">
       <?php include "_/components/php/weekend-intro.php"; ?>     
       <?php include "_/components/php/popular-categories.php"; ?>               
            </section><!-- main -->

        </div><!-- content -->
<?php include "_/components/php/footer.php"; ?>
    </section><!-- container -->
```

Comment: no need to pull. just apply `col-md-3` to the sidebar and `col-md-9 col-md-offset-3` to the other.

Comment: Hi Abhitalks, thanks much for the prompt assistance, however I edited it and it still does not work.

Comment: Hey, I figured out a more straighforward way and it solved the issue. Thanks! Have a great day, abhitalks. 

<section class="sidebar col col-lg-3">
<section class="main col col-lg-9">

Comment: In that case it isn't a sidebar. It is just another column. I was confused with the term sidebar. Anyway, if it serves your purpose, great! Cheers :)

Comment: Haha yeah, apologies, I have just started learning programming two weeks ago, and not familiar with the terminology here. Anyway, thanks much! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code. Maybe it will help you:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><?php include "_/components/php/snippet-carousel.php"; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-3 sidebar"><?php include "_/components/php/aside-social.php"; ?></section>
        <section class="col-md-9 cont-grid">
            <?php include "_/components/php/weekend-intro.php"; ?>     
            <?php include "_/components/php/popular-categories.php"; ?> 
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><?php include "_/components/php/footer.php"; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have one closing section with no opening one. And I suppose you wrap the whole thing into a container?

Comment: Hey Andi, thanks for your help.


The /section closing belongs to the container section opening that was edited; yeah, I have wrapped the whole thing into a container. I tried your method but it doenst seems to work. 
I used a layman method of <section class="sidebar col col-lg-3"> & <section class="main col col-lg-9">, it works.


And now I am figuring how to get responsive design to place sidebar on the bottom instead of top? Haha, coding is so perplexing.